# Django Rest Framework serializer field style argument

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm migrating some apps from DRF 2.4 to DRF 3.1. One of the changes that has been made is for serializer fields `widget` is no longer an valid argument. Instead we need to use `style` which according to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) expects a dict with key value pairs representing how the field is to be rendered. The example they give is:

```
# Use <input type="password"> for the input.
password = serializers.CharField(
    style={'input_type': 'password'}
)

# Use a radio input instead of a select input.
color_channel = serializers.ChoiceField(
    choices=['red', 'green', 'blue']
    style = {'base_template': 'radio.html'}
}
```

This makes sense but what I am **not** seeing anywhere is where we find the valid values of base_template and input_type. For example if I wanted to make a field rendered as checkboxes how would I do that? What I am looking for is some documentation on what the API can accept and I'm not finding it anywhere. I feel kind of stupid asking this since it seems like it should be easy to find. Could anyone enlighten me? Am I just missing something obvious here? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That link clearly says that the API is experimental. And I'm not sure what you're asking: `input_type` is clearly an HTML input type to use, and `base_template` is, well, a template to use.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to replace a select by a text input for a foreign key field, but likewise found only a few examples in the docs, e.g. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#the-style-keyword-argument-for-serializer-fields

Thanks to the debug toolbar, I could find out the default style for each serializer field and the actual location on disk: [image: django debug toolbar screenshot showing the template paths]  From there, I could look at the [source directory](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/horizontal) to see the available values.

Answer (score -2):

**Use widget attribute do define form field type:**
***Like THis ***

```
code = serializers.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

You're probably using DRF v2.x.x, which doesn't support style argument in Field class

Comment: No... in my question I am saying that I migrating from 2.4 to 3.1. I am using 3.1. My problem is I don't know where to find the valid values for `base_template` and `input_type`

Comment: Yeah Sometime before i was getting the same whatever u mentioned....    check properly  the widget....